# How to take an information from MySQL for JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I want to ask that while parsing an array there is no problem but when it comes to one line information I couldn't make it work.

For my JSON output:

```
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT description_fr FROM aboutUni where id = 1" ); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM aboutUni WHERE id = 1");

echo '{"status":"0",';
echo '"about-uni-desc":"'.$query.'",';
echo '"about-uni-desc-fr":"'.$sql3.'",';
echo '"images": [';
```

An the result is for query and sql3 variables is
Resource id #4 and Resource id #3
Why I can't get the exact information this comes from somewhere that I don't know

Comment: You still have to fetch the results after doing the query.

Comment: You should use PDO for SQL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php & as mentioned above, you are not fetching the results. Read the PHP manual, its all there. There is also a json_encode function.

Comment: ...and once you've fetched the results, use `json_encode` and be done with it, no sense in writing your own formatting. If anything, format the PHP array structure rather than write your own JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example on php.net:
https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Do this:

```
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT description_fr FROM aboutUni where id = 1" ); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM aboutUni WHERE id = 1");

$result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3);
$result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

echo '{"status":"0",';
echo '"about-uni-desc":"'.$result1['description_fr'].'",';
echo '"about-uni-desc-fr":"'.$result2['description'].'",';
echo '"images": [';
```

Comment: Thank you Michael it Worked very well. as you mentioned its better to use prewritten methods :). the one that u made is working properly. Thanks a lot

Comment: waiting for 4 more minutes to answer as marked, for sure I will.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect multiple results from your query, then you need to iterate the result sql3 something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)) {
     echo '"about-uni-desc-fr":"'.$row['description_fr'].'",';
}
```

Recommendations:

- Use PDO driver, it return the results directly as an array with various
  formats
- Use `json_encode` to return a json response

```
$array = array(
    'status' => 0,
    'about-uni-desc' => $value,
    'about-uni-desc-fr' => $value2
);
echo json_encode($array);
```